# How to set and view environment variables Google App Engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

In my app.yaml I have set some env_variables:

```
env: standard
runtime: ruby27

env_variables:
  RAILS_ENV: 'production'
  RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES: true
```

In my build details, I see some environment variables, but not the ones I have set in my app.yaml. How do I know/see if these were actually set?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply go to `App Engine` -> `Versions` and check the last column `Config`.

You can click on `View` to see the config deployed which includes the ENV VARS deployed.